# Averaging Data in Bins

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, average, scientific-computing

I have two lists: 1 is a depth list and the other is a chlorophyll list, which correspond to each other. I want to average chlorophyll data every 0.5 m depth.

```
chl  = [0.4,0.1,0.04,0.05,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.09,0.23,0.43,0.65,0.22,0.12,0.2,0.33]
depth = [0.1,0.3,0.31,0.44,0.49,1.1,1.145,1.33,1.49,1.53,1.67,1.79,1.87,2.1,2.3]
```

The depth bins are not always equal in length and do not always start at 0.0 or 0.5 intervals. The chlorophyll data always coordinates with depth data though. The chlorophyll averages also cannot be arranged in ascending order, they need to stay in correct order according to depth. The depth and chlorophyll lists are very long, so I can't do this individually.

How would I make 0.5 m depth bins with averaged chlorophyll data in them?

Goal:

```
depth = [0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5]
chlorophyll = [avg1,avg2,avg3,avg4,avg5]
```

For example:

```
avg1 = np.mean(0.4,0.1,0.04,0.05,0.4)
```

Comment: would you like using pandas ?

Comment: Is `depth = [0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5)` given or to be computed?

Comment: Depth can be made with linspace. And Ya I could use pandas

Comment: Only looking for numpy/padas solutions or "normal" python as well?

Comment: Looking for a numpy solution

Comment: @Adam You say - `The depth and chlorophyll lists are very long`. So, can you time the different approaches posted thus far on the actual data, assuming the performance might be of some interest? Given that NumPy, pandas, scipy based solutions have been posted, it would be interesting to see how these stack up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use [`numpy.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) to bin your categories.

Then use a dictionary or list comprehension to calculate results.

```
import numpy as np

chl  = np.array([0.4,0.1,0.04,0.05,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.09,0.23,0.43,0.65,0.22,0.12,0.2,0.33])
depth = np.array([0.1,0.3,0.31,0.44,0.49,1.1,1.145,1.33,1.49,1.53,1.67,1.79,1.87,2.1,2.3])

bins = np.array([0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5])

A = np.vstack((np.digitize(depth, bins), chl)).T

res = {bins[int(i)]: np.mean(A[A[:, 0] == i, 1]) for i in np.unique(A[:, 0])}

# {0.5: 0.198, 1.5: 0.28, 2.0: 0.355, 2.5: 0.265}
```

Or for the precise format you are after:

```
res_lst = [np.mean(A[A[:, 0] == i, 1]) for i in range(len(bins))]

# [nan, 0.198, nan, 0.28, 0.355, 0.265]
```

Comment: The one change I made was: bins = np.arange(0.0,50.0,0.5) because it gives me more control, but otherwise this worked well

Answer (score 11):

I'm surprised that [`scipy.stats.binned_statistic`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html) hasn't been mentioned yet. You can calculate the mean directly with it, and specify the bins with optional parameters.

```
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic

mean_stat = binned_statistic(depth, chl, 
                             statistic='mean', 
                             bins=5, 
                             range=(0, 2.5))

mean_stat.statistic
# array([0.198,   nan, 0.28 , 0.355, 0.265])
mean_stat.bin_edges
# array([0. , 0.5, 1. , 1.5, 2. , 2.5])
mean_stat.binnumber
# array([1, 1, 1, ..., 4, 5, 5])
```

Comment: I find this answer very useful. Do you know if there's a way to compute a mean_stat ignoring `nan` values? as with `np.nanmean` but using `binned_statistic`?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a vectorized NumPy solution using [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) for getting the bin shifts (indices) and [`np.add.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) for the binned summations -

```
def bin_data(chl, depth, bin_start=0, bin_length= 0.5):
    # Get number of intervals and hence the bin-length-spaced depth array
    n = int(np.ceil(depth[-1]/bin_length))
    depthl = np.linspace(start=bin_start,stop=bin_length*n, num=n+1)

    # Indices along depth array where the intervaled array would have bin shifts
    idx = np.searchsorted(depth, depthl)

    # Number of elements in each bin (bin-lengths)
    lens = np.diff(idx)

    # Get summations for each bins & divide by bin lengths for binned avg o/p
    # For bins with lengths==0, set them as some invalid specifier, say NaN
    return np.where(lens==0, np.nan, np.add.reduceat(chl, idx[:-1])/lens)
```

Sample run -

```
In [83]: chl
Out[83]: 
array([0.4 , 0.1 , 0.04, 0.05, 0.4 , 0.2 , 0.6 , 0.09, 0.23, 0.43, 0.65,
       0.22, 0.12, 0.2 , 0.33])

In [84]: depth
Out[84]: 
array([0.1  , 0.3  , 0.31 , 0.44 , 0.49 , 1.1  , 1.145, 1.33 , 1.49 ,
       1.53 , 1.67 , 1.79 , 1.87 , 2.1  , 2.3  ])

In [85]: bin_data(chl, depth, bin_start=0, bin_length= 0.5)
Out[85]: array([0.198,   nan, 0.28 , 0.355, 0.265])
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way from `pandas.cut`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'chl':chl,'depth':depth})
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.depth,bins=[0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5])).chl.mean()
Out[456]: 
depth
(0.0, 0.5]    0.198
(0.5, 1.0]      NaN
(1.0, 1.5]    0.280
(1.5, 2.0]    0.355
(2.0, 2.5]    0.265
Name: chl, dtype: float64
```